# Counting number of times a pattern occurs in a text file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, counting

I have a text file like this:

```
  2 29 31 36 44 50 54  
  15 16 19 25 50 54 29  
  9 11 14 20 24 44 30  
  12 13 15 34 36 47 28  
  12 28 3 40 45 52 46  
  5 23 24 33 48 50 1  
  5 10 11 17 39 48 35  
  3 17 21 36 37 40 53  
  11 20 27 50 54 55 24
```

I want to count how many times every number is repeated, so I am using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for n in {1..56}
do
   echo $n >> barchart.txt
   grep -o -i $n text_file.txt | wc -l >> barchart.txt
done
```

I it works fine, the only problem is that when I search for 1, it also considers 10,11,12...,19 as 1. I want to know how many times 1 is repeated alone, the same happens with all the numbers with one digit: 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and 9.  I tried to do things like: "$n" or '$n' but it doesn't work, I was also looking at the options of grep, but I don't see the correct one

Comment: Regular expressions is what you're looking for.

Comment: you should be grepping for the number wrapped in whitespace or line start/end, or just non numeric characters. as the other comment mentioned, regular expressions allow to to express such terms.

Answer (score 3):

This job is more suitable for `awk`.

Consider this `gnu-awk` command:

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '{++freq[$1]} END{for (i in freq) print i, freq[i]}' file
```

```
1 1
2 1
3 2
5 2
9 1
10 1
11 3
12 2
13 1
14 1
15 2
16 1
17 2
19 1
20 2
21 1
23 1
24 3
25 1
27 1
28 2
29 2
30 1
31 1
33 1
34 1
35 1
36 3
37 1
39 1
40 2
44 2
45 1
46 1
47 1
48 2
50 4
52 1
53 1
54 3
55 1
```

If you don't have `gnu-awk` then you can use this POSIX awk command:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) ++freq[$i]} END{for (i in freq) print i, freq[i]}' file
```

Comment: I didn't know there was two awk. Which one should I use most of the time?

Comment: If you are on Linux or other modern Unix systems then always go for `gnu-awk` as that is more feature rich and well maintained.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18 .. How do I know what awk do I have?

Comment: Most likely it is not `gnu-awk` by default on Ubuntu. You can check this Q&A for that https://superuser.com/questions/646919/how-can-i-find-my-awk-version

Comment: @DieDauphin there are far more than 2 awks. Off the top of my head there's gawk, nawk, mawk, tawk, oawk, /usr/xpg[46]/bin/awk, OSX/BSD awk, busybox awk and "one true awk", See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Other-Versions.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK#Versions_and_implementations for info on some of them.

Comment: well, I tested the version for POSIX awk ... The version for gnu-awk did something strange, but maybe it is because I don't have it installed ..

Comment: ok but POSIX awk command worked for you or you need further assistance?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use word boundaries in your pattern:

```
for n in {1..56}
do
   echo $n >> barchart.txt
   grep -o -i "\b$n\b" text_file.txt | wc -l >> barchart.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-w` to match word regexp:

```
   grep -o -w $n text_file.txt | wc -l >> barchart.txt
```

---

You can match empty strings at the start of the number (`\<`) and at the end of the number (`\>`):

```
    grep -o '\<'$n'\>' text_file.txt | wc -l >> barchart.txt
```

---

You don't need `-i` for case-insensitive matching as you're matching only digits.